Using opposing magnetic fields to find center of an area between 2 magnets?
Imagine a pendulum with the "bob" being a metal bar.  The bar has a magnet secured to each side and "swings" from a rod, between magnets on each side with opposing magnetic fields.
Is there a way, considering not all magnets of the same general size and shape have identical deflection forces, that this setup would or could (with modification) cause the bar to find center after being put in motion?
Might this work better if there was another magnet secured to the bottom of the bar plus a ferrous metal or magnet installed at the center point barely below where the bar would be when at center?
Thank you for your assistance!

Yes, if the plumb bob is on a hinge-like support (so it cannot
deflect out of a single  plane of motion) you can affix magnets
to it, and around it, to cause it to seek center by magnetic repulsion.
You can even counter-weight the plumb bob so it won't seek
vertical (because gravity ALSO affects the plumb bob, and does
NOT seek center-of-magnets, that's an error source).
Most magnetic materials, in a repulsion environment, will demagnetize
with time; there's better ways to sense a center (linear variable
differential transformer, for instance) that don't attract bits of
metal and/or get decalibrated.

Thank you for your answer.  Very helpful.  That said, this is a solution that needs to be very lightweight (less than 1 lb) and small enough to fit in a box not much bigger than a doorknob.  Would that not rule out LVDT?

LVDT sensors are small, but take electronics to drive.    Does the box have  electric power?

Yes.  Small batteries are also a possibility.

As is an external, wired solution, something I had not yet considered before your input.  An additional constraint is cost.  If possible it would need to be under $200, hopefully by a decent margin.
